# How to check validation of an IntegerField?

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have a form that have a IntegerField, this field is not required. When I submit my form I'd like to check if this field is correctly filled. The only value that are accepted are 3, 4 or an empty field.

**`forms.py`**

```
class PhaseCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    typePhase               = forms.CharField(label='Type of phase', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter the type of the phase'}))
    nbTeamPerPool           = forms.IntegerField(label='Number of teams per pool', required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder':'3 or 4'}))
    nbTeamQualified         = forms.IntegerField(label='Number of qualified', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control',
                                    'placeholder':'Enter the number of qualified'}))
    category                = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                                    'class':'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Phase
        fields = [
            'typePhase',
            'nbTeamPerPool',
            'nbTeamQualified',
            'category',
        ]

def clean_nbTeamPerPool(self, *args, **kwargs):
        nbTeamPerPool = self.cleaned_data.get("nbTeamPerPool")
        if nbTeamPerPool < 3 or nbTeamPerPool > 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The number of team per pool is between 3 and 4. Please try again.")
        return nbTeamPerPool
```

When the field is empty I have this **error** :

> '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

I understand this error, I just can't compare None with an integer, so my question is how can I compare none with integer or can you propose me a solution to make empty field accepted ?

Edit:
I have an other question that came to me now. As you can see my form have a "category" field, it's a foreign key to "Category" model and I'd like to know how can I access to fields of category in the **`clean`** method ?

Comment: Validate only if the field is not none. `if nbTeamPerPool and nbTeamPerPool < 3 or nbTeamPerPool > 4:`

Comment: Or even simpler, `if nbTeamPerPool not in (None, 3, 4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if there is any value first and then do the validation:

```
def clean_nbTeamPerPool(self, *args, **kwargs):
    nbTeamPerPool = self.cleaned_data.get("nbTeamPerPool")
    if nbTeamPerPool:
            if nbTeamPerPool < 3 or nbTeamPerPool > 4:
                raise forms.ValidationError("The number of team per pool is between 3 and 4. Please try again.")
    return nbTeamPerPool
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that ```if nbTeamPerPool:``` checks if the field is empty or not. Know it works, but I have an other question, can you check the Edit part please ?

Comment: I don't really get your second question. what do you exactly mean by "access to fields of category in the clean method"?

Comment: In my "Category" model I have a field "nbTeam" and I need this field for some validation. I'd like to make something like : `if nbTeamPerPool == 4 and self.cleaned_data.get("category").nbTeam == 17: #some code`. I don't know how to do this. `self.cleaned_data.get("category").nbTeam` doeasn't work here I think, I tried to look on the Internet but I didn't found my answer.

Comment: you can use `def clean()` method too. usually they use this method when they need to validate multiple fields depended in each other. take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/